# Can I use these alternatives instead of "in between"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, synonyms

> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many
>   shades **in between.**

To avoid repetition with another sentence, I want to find another way to say "in between".
Can I use these alternatives with basically the same meaning?

> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many
>   shades **throughout.**
>
> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many
>   shades **through.**
>
> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many
>   shades **in the way.**
>
> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many
>   shades **across.**
>
> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many **interjacent**
>   shades. (Is this too formal?)

Are there better options?

Comment: No, none of those implies _in between_ (well, _interjacent_ does but it's much too formal). _Intermediate shades_ would work.

Comment: I've never heard "interjacent" before, in 74 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from [*interjacent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interjacent), which is not very common, none of the alternatives mentioned in the question have the same meaning.

A more common adjective is [**intermediate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermediate):

> **1** : being or occurring at the middle place, stage, or degree or between extremes
>   // an *intermediate* stage of growth

So:

> Things aren't always black and white as people think. There are many *intermediate* shades.